# link to top with following div

Tags: jquery, html, mouse

I'm not exactly a developer (more a webdesigner) and I'd like to know how to make the following.
Once I saw a site that had a div with a link to scroll the page to the top.
That div showed only when the mouse was near the page vertical scrollbar and followed the mouse cursor, but only in the vertical, since it was always aligned to the right of the page.
Does anyone know a tutorial to make this?

Comment: if it follows the mouse cursor, how do you click on it?

Comment: the div with the link showed only when the mouse was aproximating the page vertical scrollbar (100 or 200 px from right), it followed the mouse only in the vertical axes, and if the mouse was over it the visitor was able to click on the link. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: [something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/eYMYd/2/)

Comment: :-) thanks!!! Yes it was very much like that, but the div hid when the mouse was over the page vertical scrollbar

Comment: @user2461766 http://jsfiddle.net/eYMYd/3/

Comment: Yes! that's it! Many, many thanks :-) Now it's only missing the link "go to top" inside the div, so that when the user clicks it the page scrolls to top! Sorry for being boring!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

`<a href="#" title="To the top of this page"><b>BACK TO TOP</b></a>`

And simply position it like any element. Easy to do with a little CSS. jQuery allows the mouse to be tracked

CSS:
`a {
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}`

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       if(e.pageX > window.innerWidth - 200)
          $("a").css("top", e.pageY);
   }); 
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Y3hQK/)

***EDIT*** Or if you mix Spokey's comment with my work: [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Y3hQK/1/)

Comment: @user2461766 If you find an answer to be acceptable you can click the checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe?
http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/3kCtJ/3/
( a very simple example )

```
$(function () {
    var $rightSide = $('#rightSide'),
        $scrollerDiv = $('#scrollerDiv'),
        viewportH = $(window).height();

    $rightSide
    .css('top', viewportH)
    .mouseenter(function () {
        //    mouse is now in #rightSide
        $scrollerDiv.fadeIn(300);
        $rightSide.mousemove(function (e) {
            var calcTop = e.pageY - viewportH - 25;
            $scrollerDiv.css('top', calcTop + 'px');
        });
    })
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $scrollerDiv.fadeOut(300);
        $rightSide.unbind('mousemove');
    })
    .click(function () {
        $(document.body).animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is very nice, thanks :-) ... but is it possible to set the div $rightSide outside the $wrapper? I tried but it didn't work!

Comment: It will be more difficult to adjust it. And depends on the actual implementation. You can put a border to the 'rightSide' and play with it, to see where and how you can place it.